# Writing an Observable to file

Tags: monix

I currently have the following code:

```
val writer: PrintWriter = ???
val linesObservable: Observable[String] = ???

val future: CancelableFuture[Unit] = linesObservable.foreach(writer.write)

writer.close()
```

My goal is to get rid of all side effects in the above snippet.

From a functional perspective, `writer` should act as resource / bracket for `future`.

Because I am using Monix version `3.0.0-RC2`, there is new `bracket` methods available for `Observable` and `Task` (maybe even more classes), which could be what I'm looking for - but I don't quite see how yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It's better to acquire `PrintWriter` as a resource so that it can be closed cleanly when its done writing.

```
val writer: Resource[Task, PrintWriter] = 
  Resource.make[Task, PrintWriter](???)(pw => Task.delay(pw.close()))

val linesObservable: Observable[String] = ???

writer.use { pw =>
  linesObservable.foreachL(pw.write)
}
```